# Applying loaders to files imported via resolve.modules in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue-loader

I have two javascript projects in separate directories within a parent directory and I want both of them to be able to import files from a common directory. The structure looks a bit like this:

```
- parentDir
  - project1
    - package.json
    - webpack.config.js
    - src
      - index.js
  - project2
    - package.json
    - webpack.config.js
    - src
      - index.js
  - common
    - components
      - CommonComponent.vue
    - application
      - app.js
```

I'd like both `project1`'s `index.js` and `project2`'s `index.js` to be able to import `CommonComponent.vue` and `app.js`.

Currently this works if I do:

```
import CommonComponent from ../../common/components/CommonComponent.vue
```

However those import paths starts to get very messy and hard to maintain the deeper into each tree we go, with huge numbers of `../`s, so I'm trying to find a way of making the imports neater and easier to manage and I came across [`resolve`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) options in webpack. So I've tried adding this to my `webpack.config.js`:

```
resolve: {
    modules: [
        path.resolve("../common/"),
        path.resolve("./node_modules")
    ]
},
```

so then the import would look like:

```
import CommonComponent from "components/CommonComponent.vue"
import app from "application/app"
```

Importing the plain js file works, but when trying to import the `.vue` file, webpack throws an error:

```
ERROR in C:/parentDir/common/components/CommonComponent.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-style-loader' in 'C:/parentDir/common/components'
```

So how can I apply webpack loaders to files imported via `resolve.modules`?

Note: importing `.vue` files from within a single project works fine, so my `module.rules` config is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the common package needed its own `node_modules`. That doesn't seem to be the case when importing a file from there directly via its path, but it is when using either `resolve.modules` or `resolve.alias` in webpack.

So the answer was to `npm init` in `common` and then to `npm install` all the dependencies and devDependencies needed there. e.g (of course these will depend on the project):

```
npm install --save vue
npm install --save-dev babel-core babel-loader css-loader less-loader vue-loader vue-template-compiler webpack
```

Once that's done, both of these webpack configs seem to have the same result as far as I can tell:

```
resolve: {
    modules: [
        path.resolve("../../common"),
        path.resolve("./node_modules")
    ]
},
```

and

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        components: path.resolve("../../common/components")
    }
}
```

Both allow a file in `project1` or `project2` to do an import like:

```
import CommonComponent from "components/CommonComponent.vue"
```